# Incorrect Email send from address

Tags: magento-1.7, email, transactional-mail

We have all the email address set in System -> Config -> Store Email Addresses.

However, the emails are being sent from the mail server.

Is there another setting that I am missing for send from Email address?

Comment: One store view. The server from address is apache@servername.com

Comment: Just to confirm if you've found out the cause of the problem?

Comment: No - we gave it to the hosting company and we are waiting now

Comment: Are you using PHP Mail or SMTP?

Comment: Whatever comes with the LAMP install. We don't have any access to the server other than the user account

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is within Magento itself. It uses PHP Mail by default where some email clients like Gmail may show the from address as from the server. One workaround is to use SMTP instead: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html